UK study visit visa proof of funds
Recently I got accepted into a course that will delivered both online and offline. For offline I have to make two visits to the UK(1st visit- 10 days, 2 visits- 4 days) within 3 months. I am currently employed and can't stay in the UK for 2 months so I have to make two visits.
Here is my question and bank statement situation, E.g.
let's say the course would cost 2500 pounds, I have to make 2 visits and let's say I planning to spend another 4000 pounds(including airfare for both trips), I have 8500 pounds in my bank account, I will be getting the salary for in-between the visits and afterwards, I also have stocks and property investments and the money from my previous visit to the UK but that is in cash so not sure how to explain the cash.
I read somewhere that to get a visa, one must have double the amount of money in the bank. I don't know how to explain this, do they consider the property and stocks, and will they consider if I write that I will be getting my regular salary between the visits and after the visits too? before my second visit(4 days), I can save some money(current pattern).

I am concerned about the amount of money I will be left with after the trips, I will be left with 2000 pounds however I will be getting the salary after my applications and visit and in-between too, so naturally the savings would increase, also the stocks I have,
In short, I am concerned considering the double the amount of money for the visa should be there, would this be considered as lack of funds?

I read somewhere that to get a visa, one must have double the amount of money in the bank. I don’t know where you read this but the UK has no such rule for a Standard Visitor visa

ok thanks, can I also include the stocks I have as proof of funds? or they only consider what you have in your bank account?

See the rules on acceptable financial institutions  and Guide to supporting documents

Thanks, link "Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?" says a lot about proportionality, however, it sometimes says people who want to spend 3-4 months' salary for a visit, my question is does this also applies for short term courses? as the courses include the fees too that alone is nearly 2 times one earns in a month, that way it won't be possible to do a course?

You can expect UKVI to consider proportionality, and whether what you’re planning to spend is reasonable/credible viewed in the the context of your overall financial situation. They should consider the stocks, as they are liquid and available to you, while a property is not a quick a source of ready cash if you need it. Put yourself in the shoes of the ECO - would you think the trip is affordable if you were the decision-maker?  Set out your financial assets clearly, and try not to over-think this aspect of your application.

Eg if you’ve got £8,500 in your bank account, say £10-12,000 in stocks, and net income after living expenses is say £1,000, probably no issue with spending £6,500 on two trips to UK for study purposes (assuming the study is relevant to eg your job/future career plans). If you’re spending £6,500 and have say just £1,000 in stocks and net income after expenses is say £50pm, probably not so good. However there’s no fixed rule, your assets are your assets, no-one can give you a definitive answer, the only way to find out is to apply.
